# attic under a flat roof

Tags: word-usage

Dictionary definition of attic: The definition of an attic is a room or space directly under the roof.
[image: attic dictionary picture]

What if a building has a flat roof? is the space/floor directly under the roof still called attic? 
An apartment where I live is on the 27th floor (top floor) of a building with a flat roof. Can I say I live in the attic?
What about other low-rise buildings, 2 floor buildings, without a pitched roof. Do they even have attics?

Comment: Do you *want* to say you live in the attic? Your situation sounds like you could spin it however you want: If you want to evoke the starving-artist-in-a-garret image, you can say you live in the attic (with a wink to people who realize your apartment is a very nice, finished space) and then when you're feeling luxe you can instead call it the penthouse (again with a wink to people who realize it's a nice, comfy apartment but not exactly a billionaire's pad). (All this assuming your apartment is, in fact, somewhere between tiny dusty space and de-luxe apartment in the sky.)

Comment: What I am trying to do, is to explain the word attic to a 9 year old kid who is studying English. The question he got was "is it still an attic if the roof of a building doesn't have a sloping roof (has a flat roof)?"

Comment: you can definitely have an attic under a flat (sloped) roof. e.g on side is 4 feet high, the other 6 feet high, and you only use it for storage. that would be an attic (to me), even if it were "finished" with drywall (no exposed rafters).

Comment: "Attics" are really a term used for houses, not apartment buildings and the like. I would be confused by you telling me you live in the attic of an apartment building. OTOH, I'd have no problem describing the space under a flat roof an "attic" if it was in a single-family home (or duplex I suppose).

Comment: @Azor-Ahai would you call the second floor of this house "an attic" then? http://cdn.trendir.com/wp-content/uploads/old/house-design/2015/12/03/1-smart-house-baufritz-first-certified-self-sufficient-home-germany.jpg

Comment: No. An attic is not a full-fledged floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In building code terms in many place in the US, an "attic" is [defined](https://books.google.com/books?id=lOmWda-KZOsC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22The%20unfinished%20space%20between%20the%20ceiling%20joists%20of%20the%20top%20story%20and%20the%20roof%20rafters.%22&source=bl&ots=4C83XJu57U&sig=WIBth1N8SvXQUjtisIy2UMLGayY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAyKncoq_WAhWLyIMKHZubDEEQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22The%20unfinished%20space%20between%20the%20ceiling%20joists%20of%20the%20top%20story%20and%20the%20roof%20rafters.%22&f=false) specifically as "The unfinished space between the ceiling joists of the top story and the roof rafters." So, by that definition, no rafters = no attic.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, so according to this definition, buildings without a pitched roof have no attics then.

Comment: i think the key word here is "unfinished".  the shape does not really matter. an attic is kinda like leftover space at the top of the building.

Comment: If there's a unfinished leftover space at the top, it's an attic. But an attic can also contain a bedroom, someone can live in an attic bedroom, in which case it's finished.
would you say that these buildings have no attic? or could you say the top floor is an attic?
https://ibb.co/mhvLyk

Comment: According to the building code, the space has to be below rafters, which are  diagonal members (indicating a pitched roof). However, that's just the technical definition.